# Mill's ratio and convergence almost surely

Tags: limsup-and-liminf, almost-everywhere

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of independent random variables N[0,1].

Show that:
$$
\mathcal{P}(\underbrace{lim sup}_{n \longmapsto \infty} \frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt{log \ n}} = \sqrt{2}) = 1
$$

I've been asked to compute it by using the Mill's ratio, so using that: 1- $\Phi(x)$ ~ $x^{-1} \phi(x)$.
So i was thinking about computing:
$$
\mathcal{P}\left(|X_n| \geq \sqrt{log \ n} \sqrt{2}\right) 
$$

but I don't know how to proceed.